# Why does spark-shell spit out NotSerializableException while sbt console does not?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

There is only one `NotSerializableException` I cannot understand.  Start an EMR cluster with Spark 1.5.0, then enter the shell `spark-shell --master local` (it makes no difference if you choose `yarn-client` over `local`).

then run the following code:

```
class MaybeSerializable() {
  def add(i: Int) = i + 1
}

val foo = new MaybeSerializable()

sc.makeRDD(1 to 1000).map(foo.add).reduce(_ + _)
```

I promise you it will cause a `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable`

Now create an sbt project using the same version of Spark `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.0"`, and enter the `sbt console`, then run

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

val sc = new SparkContext("local", "shell")

class MaybeSerializable() {
  def add(i: Int) = i + 1
}

val foo = new MaybeSerializable()

sc.makeRDD(1 to 1000).map(foo.add).reduce(_ + _)
```

And I promise you it will work! No exception!

If someone could explain this I would be very happy.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the inconsistency of behavior, I'm not an Spark expert, but I'd say that in the first case, when using Yarn EMR, the whole "MaybeSerializable" class gets serialized for sure and it gets sent to the executors by the driver. As it is not serializable, you get the "NotSerializableException" exception.

On the other hand, in the second case, I'm not so sure the class is getting serialized, and that's why you don't get the exception. The underlying architecture is driving the need or not for serialization. As you're using sbt, I wouldn't be surprised if the driver is not sending a serialized version of the class to any process. In that case, as it is not needed, it doesn't matter if the class is serializable or not.

I can reproduce the first issue in my computer with standalone and I get rid of it making the class serializable this way: "class MaybeSerializable() extends Serializable". That's a best practice I use (and/or anonymous functions) to  make sure that my code will run in any cluster type and the serialization behavior will be consistent across clusters.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I'd recommend avoiding `extends Serializable` and use case classes to ensure clear separation between data and functions.  You have to be careful putting `extends Serializable` everywhere because this can create memory leaks.  Anyway, I still don't quite understand why running Spark inside an SBT console is different.  I didn't think Spark is SBT aware!

Comment: As you say, using case classes for data ensures a clear separation. For functions using objects has better performance in general than serializable classes. If you define MaybeSerializable as an object, it's another way to get rid of the "Task not serializable" exception in a performant way.